# Finding all real $x$ such that $1+\sum_{j=1}^n\sin{\frac{j\pi x}{n+1}} = 0$, where $n=18$.

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

> The task is to find all $ x \in \mathbb R $ such that
>
> $$ 1 + \sum_{j=1}^n \sin{\frac{j\pi x}{n + 1}} = 0, \qquad n = 18 $$

### What I have tried

Using the following formulas:
$$1. \sin{x} + \sin{y} = 2\sin{\frac{x + y}{2}}\cos{\frac{x - y}{2}} $$
$$2. \cos{x} + \cos{y} = 2\cos{\frac{x + y}{2}}\cos{\frac{x - y}{2}} $$
$$3. \sin{x}\sin{y} = \frac{1}{2} (\cos{(x - y)} - \cos{(x + y)}) $$

#### First approach

$$ 1 + \sin{\frac{\pi x}{19}} + \sin{\frac{18\pi x}{19}} + \sin{\frac{2 \pi x}{19}} + \sin{\frac{17\pi x}{19}} + ... + \sin{\frac{9 \pi x}{19}} + \sin{\frac{10 \pi x}{19}} = 0 $$

Using formula 1:

$$ 1 + 2\sin{\frac{\pi x}{2}} (\cos{\frac{17\pi x}{19}} + \cos{\frac{15\pi x}{19}} + ... + \cos{\frac{\pi x}{19}})$$

Skipping some steps, we get:

$$ 1 + 2\sin{\frac{\pi x}{2}}\cos{\frac{9\pi x}{38}}(2\cos{\frac{3\pi x}{38} + 1})(2\cos{\frac{\pi x}{38}} + 1) = 0 $$

From here I couldn't find a way to go further

#### Second approach

Multiply both sides by $ \sin{\frac{\pi x}{38}} $:

$$ \sin{\frac{\pi x}{38}} (1 + \sin{\frac{\pi x}{19}} + \sin{\frac{2\pi x}{19}} + \sin{\frac{3 \pi x}{19}} + ... + \sin{\frac{17 \pi x}{19}} + \sin{\frac{18 \pi x}{19}}) = 0 $$

Using formula number 3

$$ \sin{\frac{\pi x}{38}} + \frac{1}{2}(\cos{\frac{\pi x}{38}} - \cos{\frac{3\pi x}{38}} + \cos{\frac{3\pi x}{38}} - \cos{\frac{5\pi x}{38}} + ... + \cos{\frac{35\pi x}{38}} - \cos{\frac{37\pi x}{38}}) = 0$$

$$ \sin{\frac{\pi x}{38}} - \sin{\frac{\pi x}{2}}\sin{\frac{18\pi x}{38}} = 0 $$

From here I couldn't find any way to go further

Any *hints* will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
The upper-most formula had a mistake, but now it is up to date.

**PS**
The problem is supposed to be solvable assuming you have high-school level math (i.e only simple trigonometric formulas are allowed, no complex numbers, no derivatives for the sine and cosine functions).

Also, [this equation on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2B%20(sum%20sin(j%20*%20pi%20*%20x%20%2F%2019),%20j%20%3D%201%20to%2018)%20%3D%200) shows the following solution:
$ x = \frac{19}{2}(4n - 1), n \in \mathbb Z $

**Update 2**: Using @Doug M's answer, I managed to conclude that ($ \sin{\frac{\pi x}{19}} = 1 $ and $ \cos{\frac{\pi x}{19}} = 0 $), which equalates to $ \frac{\pi x}{19} = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n, n \in \mathbb Z $ is one of the solutions to the equation

Comment: @FelixMarin Apologies for that, I have actually made a typo in my upper formula. Now it is up to date!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Isn't it what I described in my second approach?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the series by $\frac {\sin \frac {\pi x}{19}}{\sin \frac {\pi x}{19}}$

Then use 
$\sin A\sin B = \frac 12 \cos  (A-B) - \frac 12 \cos (A+B)$

And the series will telescope.

$1+\sum_\limits{j=1}^{18} \frac {\sin \frac{j\pi}{19}\sin \frac {\pi x}{19}}{\sin\frac {\pi x}{19}}$

$1+\sum_\limits{j=1}^{18} \left(\frac {\cos \frac{(j-1)\pi}{19}}{2\sin\frac {\pi x}{19}} - \frac {\cos \frac{(j+1)\pi}{19}}{2\sin\frac {\pi x}{19}}\right)$

$1+\frac{\cos 0 + \cos \frac {\pi x}{19} - \cos \frac {18\pi x}{19} - \cos \pi x}{2\sin \frac {\pi x}{19}} = 0$

let $y = \frac {\pi x}{19}$

$2\sin y + 1 + \cos y - \cos 18y - \cos 19y = 0$

(multiplying through by $\sin y$ has introduced an artificial solution at $\sin y = 0$)

$y = \frac {3\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$ is a solution, implying $x = \frac {57}{2}$

As for the others....

If we expand the $\cos 19 y, \cos 18 y$ terms we could turn this into a function of powers of $cos y$ and $sin y$ but we still have a 19 (or 17 degree when we factor out the two identified factors) degree polynomial to factor.

I put it into wolfram alpha and none of the other solutions are particularly nice.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin+y++%2B+1+%2B+cos+y+-+cos+18y+-+cos+19y+%3D+0

This is as far as I know how to take it.

Comment: From here I could find x = pi / 2, but not solve the equation.

Comment: I think the term to the far right should be cos(pi * x) instead of cos(pi). Given this, I don't understand how did you simplify/

Comment: Indeed, I forgot what I had yesterday.  I am going to have to come back to this.

Comment: Have you found anything yet? This problem has been tormenting me for days...

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $x$ s.t. $-(n+1) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \sin (j\pi x)$. 
If $x\not = 1$, then the RHS is the imaginary part of
$$
X = \sum_{j=0}^n (\cos(j\pi x) + i\sin(j\pi x))= \sum_{j=0}^n \left( \cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x) \right)^j = \frac{1 - \left( \cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x) \right)^{n+1}}{1 - \left( \cos(\pi x) + i\sin(\pi x) \right)}
$$
$$
X = \frac{1 - (\cos \pi + i \sin \pi)^{x(n+1)}}{1 - (\cos \pi + i \sin \pi)^x} = \frac{1 - (-1)^{x(n+1)}}{1 - (-1)^x}
$$

Its imaginary part is of course $0$, so it doesn't depend on $x$. Just check what happens for $x = 1$.

Comment: The problem is supposed to be for high-school level math (i.e you can only use basic trigonometric formulas similar to the ones I have used in my approaches, and no complex numbers are allowed). Thanks anyway!